# How to configure PHPUnit Test Suites for NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

From [Recent improvements in PHPUnit-support](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/recent-improvements-in-phpunit-support)

[image]

I can configure test suites, but what will testsuite files look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Chapter 7 - Organizing Tests](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/organizing-tests.html), including [Composing a Test Suite Using the File System](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.filesystem) and [Composing a Test Suite Using XML Configuration](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration)